# ArgumentError in UsersController#create wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

First up, I'm using rails 5.1.2. I've used Michael Hartl's tutorial as a starting point for a web app and I've run into a snag.

When I try to sign up to the website while running a dev server on localhost, I get an error after I submit the user details.

```
 ArgumentError in UsersController#create wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
 Extracted source (around line #21):

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url

 Rails.root: /home/krefey/workspace/gaming-sonar
 Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

I *think* it is because I have installed ActiveAdmin and Devise and that is causing issues with the user model that has been setup.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }, allow_nil: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now.to_datetime)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
      update_columns(reset_digest:  User.digest(reset_token), reset_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end


  private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
      email.downcase!
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
end
```

user_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url



  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Create my account') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, from what I can tell, it feels like that when the create function is being called, it is supposed to be assigning the parameters (user_params) to the @user variable.

I strongly suspect that the devise line at the start of the user.rb file that I added is the culprit, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You passed incorrect parameter in `User.digest` function, `activation_token` is in `self.activation_token`.

try to change below line in `user.rb` model:

```
self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
```

with

```
self.activation_digest = User.digest(self.activation_token)
```

Comment: That did not appear to have helped.  I still got the same error.  Thanks for the response.I tried commenting out the devise call at the start of the user.rb file and that has fixed the problem. Of course, now I have a new problem.  Working out how to properly integrate devise so I can use active admin.